# List of dynamic and EPPlus LoadFromCollection

Tags: c#, excel, dapper, epplus

I have list of dynamic objects which I am getting by calling an api. Now, I need to load it EPPlus using,

```
List<dynamic> listOfDynamicObjects = Get();
worksheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(listOfDynamicObjects,...
```

Now I am getting `column out of range` exception. Is there is a way to load dynamic objects?  List is coming from Dapper.

**Update:** I used DataTable instead of List and it worked.

Comment: List<dynamic> is coming from DB using Dapper

Comment: Yes second line. For now I uses DataTable instead and it worked

Comment: @user960567 you can also use `LoadFromDataReader`. Rows returned from a database aren't really dynamic, they come with full schema data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rows loaded from a database aren't dynamic or arbitrary, they have a very strict schema that's returned along with the data. You can use Dapper's `ExecuteDataReader` and EPPlus's `LoadFromDataReader` instead of going through `dynamic` and losing the type information:

```
using(var con=new SqlConnection(someConnectionString))
using(var reader=con.ExecuteReader(query))
{
    sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataReader(reader);
}
```

This way you avoid caching the data twice - once in the DataTable or List and once in the Excel package